# How to document multi-language tags in SO documentation, e.g. Spark?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation, documentation-proposals

Let's say I want to help document Spark. Now Spark framework has APIs in multiple languages including `Java`, `Scala`, `Python` having the same functionality. SO Documentation already has two tags `apache-spark` & `pyspark`. Keeping same **topics** and similar examples at multiple tags would be cumbersome and inelegant.

If you see the [official documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#basics), it's very cleanly tabbed for the 3 different languages. Can we have such a feature in SO Documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would take a look at what has been done for the [.NET Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/topics) Documentation. Mostly the examples use C#, but there is a [Getting started with .NET Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/14/getting-started-with-net-framework) section that illustrates some of the languages most frequently used with the platform.

What's most important to recognize, I think, is that neither Spark nor the .NET Framework is a language, and so intensive language instruction is not relevant in their documentation. Framework documentation should assume basic programming language competency and illustrate usage of API classes, methods, and conventions, dropping down to intensive language detail only when it is particularly needed or relevant. Not every "How do you call X method" needs a trilingual example.

Comment: In that case, we should propose deleting `pyspark` tag in SO doc.